# ExtJS 4 Grid Update

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

Sorry if this is a stupid question, but I'm trying to learn ExtJS ;)

Im create model.

```
Ext.regModel('item',{
```

Create data store.

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
        model: 'pitem',
```

Create Grid

```
var grid = new Ext.grid.GridPanel({
        store: store,
```

Work good and load data on document load succcessful. But now I need to update grid every 30 minutes or by clicking the refresh button. How can I execute the update action?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The part with upgrading store every 30 minutes :

```
var task = 
{
   run : function() 
   {
      store.load();
   },
   interval: 1800000 //(1 second = 1000)
}

Ext.TaskManager.start(task);
```

Answer (score 2):

To reload the data of your Store, just call `store.load()`.

Comment: Its mean that store automaticly update all data where its assigned like dataStore?

Answer (score 1):

you can load data directly using store.loadData() function.